# How to use most GPIOs of ESP12e for simple push button inputs and led outputs?

Tags: esp8266

I'm using esp12e for my project and encountered difficulty in using more than 5 GPIOs. I have connected GPIO15 to Ground, GPIO0 to VCC, Enable to VCC (Connections as as per attached image). I'm able to use only GPIO4,5,12,13 & 14 (5 IOs) as normal IOs. How can I use more pins as IOs? [image: Connections]

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/402066/esp8266-free-gpios-for-relay-switching/404845#404845

Answer (score 0):

This is the setup I have used for 4 relays and 4 touch switches on ESP8266-E. But there is occasional problem with relay4 as the connected wall light blinks rapidly in sync with onboard LED. I think instead of GPIO-2/D4, I should have used GPIO-3/RX pin.

[image]